# what percentage of people that telephone visit the clinic for consultancy?

Tags: probability

At a particular free counselling clinic the social workers are so busy that only 66% of potential new patients that telephone are able to immediately talk with a social worker when they call.The other 34% are asked to leave their phone numbers.About 70% of the time a social worker is able to return the call on the same day and other 30% of the time the caller is contacted on the following day. Experience at this clinic indicate that the probability that a caller will actually visit the clinic for consultation is 0.7 if the caller was immediately able to speak to a social worker,0.8 if the patient's call was returned the same day and 0.2 if the call was returned following day.

Can someone gives some hints to solve this question?

Comment: Can you fix your grammar and typo's please so we know what is needed to know? Thanks.

Comment: Bayes' Theorem. You have been given the values of several conditional probabilities. You must parse your question carefully in order to write down these probabilities and then formulate the probability you require in terms of those.

Answer (score 1):

Straighforward calculation:

66% of the caller are able to immediately talk with a social worker. And 70% of them  will actually visit the clinic for consultation: $0.66\cdot 0.7$

34% of the caller are not able to immediately talk with a social worker. 70% of the time a social worker is able to return the call on the same day. And 80% of them  will actually visit the clinic for consultation:$0.34\cdot 0.7\cdot 0.8$

I hope you see the pattern, how it is calculated. You just need the callers, whose call was return at the next day. Then add up all probabilities.

Hint: The percentage of visiting the clinic for consultancy people, who have telephoned is $67.28\%$